# Array of all RGB permutations in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, permutation, rgb

I am trying to make an array of all the possible colours made out of RGB values. Every permutation between r=0 b=0 g=0 to r=255 b=255 g=255. The idea of my function is that when it's called you supply a limit number so that the function returns an array of RGB values up to this number to stop it returning all 16 million. The code I have below returns 767 permutations (256 * 3) how do I get this to return the full 16 million up to the limit number I provide?

```
function colourArray($number) {

    $r = 0;

    $g = 0;

    $b = 0;

    $i = 0;

    while ($i <= $number) {

        $colours[] = array($r,$g,$b);

        $r++;

        $i++;

    }

    $i = 0;

    while ($i <= $number) {

        $colours[] = array($r,$g,$b);

        $g++;

        $i++;

    }

    $i = 0;

    while ($i <= $number) {

        $colours[] = array($r,$g,$b);

        $b++;

        $i++;

    }


    return $colours;

}
```

Comment: By the looks of it you need to nest your while loops. But having 16 million arrays might cause a overload, timeout or something else

Comment: Is this just an excercise? Because I'm sure there are much better ways to solve your problem than computing this.

Comment: Yes this is just an exercise for fun.

Comment: Take a piece of paper and pretend you're php interpreter. Now run your code. This way you'll find why exactly you're failing in such a trivial task.

Comment: Why would you even loop to check the values, when casting to an int and checking the value is either above or below a certain threshold would be much more efficient. In short, you don't need to loop every possible value to determine if a value is within a given valid range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting your loops is the trick. Try the following example. I've replaced your while-loops by foreach-loops with the PHP range function, and nested (i.e. loop-inside-a-loop) them inside eachother:

```
function colourArray($number) {
        $colours = array();
        foreach(range(0,$number) as $r) {
            foreach(range(0,$number) as $g) {
                foreach(range(0,$number) as $b) {
                    $colours[] = array($r,$g,$b);
                }
            }
        }
        return $colours;
}
```

**References**:

http://php.net/range

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Why would one prefer `foreach` with `range()` over `for` here?

Comment: Yea, I wonder this too. I prefer foreach when it's an array of objects, or array of arrays. Whenever I'm looping through what is essentially a set of numbers, I always use for().

Comment: It could have been a for loop just as well, in my opinion. Foreach is shorter though, in this example. Foreach creates a copy of the range(0,$number) itself. Although I should've declared the range() only once, in hindsight.

Comment: He's a pythonist in disguise :)

Answer (score 1):

I almost agree with DickW, but I'm partial to for() loops for numeric ranges.

```
<?php

function color_array($range)
{
    $result = array();

    for ($r = 0; $r <= $range; $r++) {
        for ($g = 0; $g <= $range; $g++) {
            for ($b = 0; $b <= $range; $b++) {
                $result[] = array($r, $g, $b);
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r(color_array(5));
```

Comment: This is fine too, indeed. It's about personal preference if you ask me.