# HTML - nested for loop outputting span elements

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to write the code that would output different colors each time it passed through the loop in a  element to create a color wheel type thing. I am still a newbie in PHP and how it interacts with html, but here is the code I have so far. This outputs a bunch of different span elements but they are all the same color where they should be different each time it loops. BTW the iterator is set to 50 in a separate file that ive included.

```
 <h1>Using Iterator: <?php  echo $iterator; ?></h1>

<?php
$red = 0;
$green = 0;
$blue = 0;

// LOOPS HERE
for($red = 0; $red < 255; $red+$iterator){

    for($green = 0; $green < 255; $green+$iterator){

        for($blue = 0; $blue < 255; $blue+$iterator){
            echo "<span style='background-color: rgb(0, 50, 150)'
                    title='#003296'></span>";

        $hexred = sprintf('%02x', $red);

        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You are telling it to output `background-color: rgb(0, 50, 150)` 255 x 255 x 255 times. You are not changing the colour.

Comment: you can check solution here 
http://www.herethere.net/~samson/php/color_gradient/

Comment: Unless it's actually `+= $iterator`, each of the for loops is infinite.

Comment: Don't Panic, thank you this was the problem and makes a lot of sense now that you pointed it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
echo "<span style='background-color: rgb(0, 50, 150)'
                title='#003296'></span>";
```

With this,

```
echo "<span style='background-color: rgb($red, $green, $blue)'
                title='#".$red.$green.$blue."'></span>";
```

Comment: I tried this solution but only resulting in the color black being output over and over rather than blue

Comment: @NandanBhat with out iterator increment, it will be always 0.

Comment: My problem was not using =+ where i was just using +$iterator to increment. However I ended up needing to change what you suggested in your comment as well. Thanks again everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Your code generally works. You just need to do two things:

1. increment properly in your for loops with `+=` instead of `+`
2. use the color variables in your output

Like this:

```
$iterator = 50;
for($red = 0; $red < 255; $red+=$iterator){

    for($green = 0; $green < 255; $green+=$iterator){

        for($blue = 0; $blue < 255; $blue+=$iterator){
            echo "<span style='background-color: rgb($red, $green, $blue)'
                        title='#003296'>&nbsp;</span>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @bccheatha I think you should mark this answer "Accepted" :) Contributor has invested his time on your question. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this, homie.

```
<?php
$colours = colourArray();

// Be careful playing with $step! 0 will likely crash your program. 
// This function returns an array of all possible RGB values in increments
// dictated by $step
// I took this function from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268983/array-of-all-rgb-permutations-in-php?answertab=active#tab-top
function colourArray($step = 25) {
    $colours = array();
    foreach(range(0,255,$step) as $r) {
        foreach(range(0,255,$step) as $g) {
            foreach(range(0,255,50) as $b) {
                $colours[] = array($r,$g,$b);
            }
        }
    }
    return $colours;
}

foreach ($colours as $spectrum) {
    $r = $spectrum[0];
    $g = $spectrum[1];
    $b = $spectrum[2];

    echo "<span style=\"background-color: rgb($r, $g, $b)\">$r, $g, $b</span>";
}
```